# Adding special characters to a String using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, character

I have string
`CEE0001`
and i want to add `+` sign between each character of the String.

eg: `C+E+E+0+0+0+1`

How do i do this using jQuery.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can `split` the string and `join` the returned array with `+`.

```
var s = 'CEE0001'.split('').join('+');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String.prototype.chunk = function(n) {
var ret = [];
for(var i=0, len=this.length; i < len; i += n) {
   ret.push(this.substr(i, n))
}
return ret
};

"CEE0001".chunk(1).join('+');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "CEE0001";
var output = str.split('').join('+');
```

Comment: VenkateshKumar mentioned var str = CEE0001; But str should be a string means var str = "CEE0001"

Comment: while i am answering i didnt get that answers